# How to prioritize sum before string conversion in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, sum, data-conversion

Is there a way instead to do like this

"4"+4+3 which will be equal with "443" to somehow do first 4+3 like the result to be "47" (as string)? I have tried in many ways, but no one seems to work. Some ideeas? Thanks.

ps. Not switching numbers

Comment: Operator precendence/associativity problems? Use the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping)! …or an extra variable.

Comment: What did you try? It seems like there are very few options for what you could have done wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Put the values you want to add in brackets and then concatenate

```
"4"+(4+3)
```

Comment: To be honest, I'd prefer to make it as explicit as possible as something like `var sum = 4 + 3; var message = "4"+sum` but yes, brackets will work. The problem there is somebody coming in and removing them or something and suddenly you're back to concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
console.log("4"+ (4+3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const num1=4;
    const num2=3
    
    console.log("4"+(num1+num2));
```

you can use the following code